# Could not load file or assembly 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.0.316.0

Tags: c#, nuget, token, nuget-package, stackexchange.redis

We are using the latest version of Owin Security RedisTokenProviders but we have problem:

> Could not load file or assembly 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   .net 4.8

Comment: I think we are going to need a little more info here about your setup etc

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling StackExchange.Redis library from nuget or cli?
Something on package manager console like: 
Uninstall-package StackExchange.Redis
Install-package StackExchange.Redis

Comment: Check that versions in packages.config and app.config are the same

Comment: try removing the reference, uninstall the package and reinstall the package..also close visual studio and reopen visual studio

Comment: sometimes, deleting bin and obj and rebuilding the folder also helps